How can I dynamically add methods to a Python class at runtime while preserving their type annotations?
from typing import Callable

class MyClass:
    pass

def dynamic_method(self, x: int, y: str) -> str:
    return f"{x} - {y}"

setattr(MyClass, 'dynamic_method', dynamic_method)


instance = MyClass()
print(instance.dynamic_method(42, "hello"))  # This works


from inspect import signature
print(signature(MyClass.dynamic_method))

The dynamically added method works as expected when called, but the type annotations are not properly associated with the method. When I inspect the method signature, it doesn’t show the annotations I defined in dynamic_method.

What output are you expecting, and what you are seeing? I see 42 - hello and (self, x: int, y: str) -> str, at least in Python 3.11 and later.

this behavior happens because setattr directly adds the function to the class as an attribute but doesn't fully bind it as a proper method with the expected type annotations and metadata. The inspect.signature function doesn't detect type annotations properly in this setup because dynamic_method was not defined as a method within the class initially.
To ensure that the dynamically added method retains its type annotations, you can use FunctionType and explicitly set the annotations attribute or bind the function properly using the types.MethodType. Here's how you can address this:
Solution Using FunctionType
python
from types import FunctionType
from inspect import signature

class MyClass:
    pass

def dynamic_method(self, x: int, y: str) -> str:
    return f"{x} - {y}"

# Ensure the function is properly bound and retains annotations
dynamic_method_with_annotations = FunctionType(
    dynamic_method.__code__,
    dynamic_method.__globals__,
    dynamic_method.__name__,
    dynamic_method.__defaults__,
    dynamic_method.__closure__
)
dynamic_method_with_annotations.__annotations__ = 
dynamic_method.__annotations__

setattr(MyClass, 'dynamic_method', dynamic_method_with_annotations)

instance = MyClass()
print(instance.dynamic_method(42, "hello"))  # This works
print(signature(MyClass.dynamic_method))  # This now shows annotations


setattr should be all you need. There's nothing special about function-valued class attributes until you do attribute lookup on an instance, at which point a method object is produced.
